# Repetition control structure

Tags: java

This is the question
[image: Click here for the question]

This is the code I worked on:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class FlooringTiles {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i, N, length, width, tiles, extra, total;

        N = sc.nextInt();

        if (N < 1 || N > 100) {
            System.out.print("Invalid number of labs. Please try again (1-100)");
        } else
            for (i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
                width = sc.nextInt();
                if (width < 1 || width > 10000) {
                    System.out.print("Invalid width. Please try again (1-10000)");
                }
                length = sc.nextInt();
                if (length < 1 || length > 10000) {
                    System.out.print("Invalid length. Please try again (1-10000)");
                }

                tiles = (length * width) / (30 * 30);
                extra = ((length * width) % (30 * 30)) / (30 * 30);
                total = tiles + extra;

                System.out.println("Case #" + i + ": " + total);
            }
    }
}
```

I can't seem to get the same output as the sample given in the picture when I use the same sample input. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Don’t post images, include sample data and expected result as text instead. Also clarify in more detail what goes wrong with your code. As a side note, when validating input you can’t just print an error message you also need to take action in your code to handle the situation. Right now your code only continues as nothing was wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you use the area of a tile in your calculation to calculate the "extra" tiles. 
You have to calculate the number of rows you need and the number of cols you need separately.

So image you have a length of 301, so you divide this by 30 and you get 10,0333, by using Math.ceil we can round up to 11.

Like this:

```
int rowsNeeded = (int) Math.ceil(length / 30);
int colsNeeded = (int) Math.ceil(width / 30);
int tiles = rowsNeeded * colsNeeded;
```

Of course you could also use modulo to calculate the number of rows you need.

Like if length%30 != 0 add 1 to length/30